# Building an xslt variable with elements from multiple files

Tags: xslt

I'm no XSLT guru and couldn't find a similar example online. I'd like to assemble a list of apps from multiple files into a single var that can be used for searching.

Basically when I replace the original variable decleration with the new one, XSLT doesn't like it. I did output the variable contents to a file and they are identical in formatting of the XML elements so it must be failing around some metadata linked to the variable somewhere.

XML element format in all the files

```
<include-application name="appname" type="blah"/>
```

Orignal variable

```
<xsl:variable name="applications" select="board/packaging/*/include-application"/>
```

New variable definition

```
<xsl:variable name="applications">
    <xsl:copy-of select="board/packaging/*/include-application"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="board/packaging/applications/include">
        <xsl:variable name="appset" as="xs:string" select="@name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="includefile" as="xs:string" select="concat('../share/appsets/', $appset, '.xml')"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document($includefile)/applications/include-application"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Then when I try to access the elements to pick something, it fails with the new variable definition (line 39 is the first one in block below).

```
<xsl:variable name="type" select="$applications[@name = $appname]/@type"/>
<xsl:variable name="appid" select="$app-names/application-package-name[@name = $appname]/appid[@type = $type]/@value"/>
```

XPath error : Invalid type
runtime error: file xslt/blah.xslt line 39 element variable
Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'type'.

Thanks

David

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using, exactly?

Comment: xsltproc on linux/osx (libxml2)

Comment: Then the people who thought you were using XSLT 2.0 are mistaken. The "as" attributes are presumably ignored (an XSLT 1.0 processor ignores unknown attributes if the version attribute is set to 2.0). The failure is presumably because you are using a result-tree-fragment in a way that XSLT 1.0 does not allow, and adding an "as" attribute will not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using XSLT 2.0, as evidenced by your use of `as=`, you need to declare the memory organization of your variable so as to act on it later.  I think all you need to do is simply change the first line of your variable to be:

```
<xsl:variable name="applications" as="element(include-application)*">
  ...
```

That will tell the processor not to build a tree, but rather, to build a node set.

There is helpful information and a diagram on page 223 of my XSLT book that is available for free download on a "try and buy" basis at http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/training/#ptux ... if you decide not to pay for the book, please delete the copy that you download for free.

Comment: If you are not getting a constraint error on the declaration of `$applications`, then the memory organization should now be ready for your reference, so I cannot understand why you are still getting the error when accessing it.  I will leave it for others to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be that the variable contains a XML fragment instead than a node-set (see [this](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html) for example) - different XSLT processor have different extension functions to do the conversion - for example using a Microsoft processor you would do:

```
<xsl:variable name="type" select="msxsl:node-set($applications)[@name = $appname]/@type"/>
```

other processors have different functions (or the same function in a different namespace)

Comment: I doubt that will work because the way the variable is declared dictates that `$applications` is a document node.  Furthermore, a Microsoft processor likely would not work because of the use of XSLT 2.0 features (such as `as=`) and last I heard Microsoft doesn't support XSLT 2.0.

Comment: I'm on linux and also osx

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of the above answers and looking into it more deeply, I used the exslt extension for converting to a node set and it works flawlessly now.

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
...
<xsl:variable name="applications" as="element(include-application)*">
...
<xsl:variable name="type" select="exslt:node-set($applications)/include-application[@name = $appname]/@type"/>
```